# Alignment problem of footnotes inside tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, pifont

I have a problem with footnotes inside tables. I am using the pifont package to produce dots (`\ding{108}`). These dots should be aligned. This works very well until I add more then 9 footnotes. Then the dots are no longer centered because the whole expression including the footnote number is centered. This then causes a shift of the dots with footnote numbers of 10 or higher to the left.

A MWE is shown below. The reason why i use `threeparttable` is not shown in the MWE. It is however necessary for other things in the table that are omitted in the MWE. Does anybody know how to exclude footnotes from centering or has a workaround?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{footnote}


\begin{document}
Previous 1\footnote{bla1}\\
Previous 2\footnote{bla2}\\
Previous 3\footnote{bla3}\\
Previous 4\footnote{bla4}\\
Previous 5\footnote{bla5}\\
Previous 6\footnote{bla6}\\
Previous 7\footnote{bla7}\\
Previous 8\footnote{bla8}\\

    \begin{savenotes}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{lc}


                \textbf{blabalabaa} & \textbf{blabalabal}  \\ \hline\hline
                First item  & \ding{108}\footnote{bla9} \\  
                Second item & \ding{108}\footnote{bla10} \\  


            \end{tabular} 

        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{savenotes} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess `{tabular}{ll}` is not an option?

Comment: It is not an option. The table is much bigger and more complicated as shown in the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the footnote is always the last thing in the tabular entry, then this works.  This way, as shown in my MWE, it even works when some of the lines have no footnotes.

EDITED to take Bernard's suggestion to use `\rlap{}` instead of `\makebox[0pt][l]{}` for the zero-width case.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{footnote}


\begin{document}
Previous 1\footnote{bla1}\\
Previous 2\footnote{bla2}\\
Previous 3\footnote{bla3}\\
Previous 4\footnote{bla4}\\
Previous 5\footnote{bla5}\\
Previous 6\footnote{bla6}\\
Previous 7\footnote{bla7}\\
Previous 8\footnote{bla8}\\

    \begin{savenotes}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{lc}


                \textbf{blabalabaa} & \textbf{blabalabal}  \\ \hline\hline
                Zeroeth item  & \ding{108}
\\  
                First item  & \ding{108}\rlap{\footnote{bla9}} \\  
                Second item & \ding{108}\rlap{\footnote{bla10}} \\  


            \end{tabular} 

        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{savenotes} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

If there is more that follows the footnote in the tabular cell, then one could, for example, use `\makebox[8pt][l]{\footnote{bla9}}`, so that all `tabular` footnotes occupied equal width.  More provisions would be needed with this finite-width approach  if some lines did or did not contain footnotes.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Using `\rlap{footnote{blah}}` would be a shorter code.

Comment: @Bernard Yes it would (for the zero-width case), and so I have revised.  Thanks!